# gmock: call matcher on a range of elements of std::vector

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I want to test a function that reorders array elements so that even numbers will be at the beginning of a std::vector:

```cpp
void EvenOdd(vector<int>* A_ptr);
```

This is a working test I wrote:

```cpp
MATCHER(first_odd_implies_second_odd, "first element is odd and second even!")
{
    auto isOdd = [](auto x) -> bool { return x & 1; };  
    return !isOdd(arg[0]) || isOdd(arg[1]);
}

TEST(Arrays_EvenOdd, simpleTest)
{
    std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 6, 3 };
    EvenOdd(&v);
    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end() - 1; ++it)
    {
        ASSERT_THAT(it, first_odd_implies_second_odd());
    }
}
```

After the call to EvenOdd() I expect v to be i.e. [6, 2, 4, 8, 9, 1, 3]. All the even numbers are before any odd number.

Is there a way to remove the for loop from the `Arrays_EvenOdd.simpleTest` test?
I'm looking for something to apply `first_odd_implies_second_odd` matcher to the range:

```cpp
[v.begin(), v.end() - 1]
```

Comment: Are you looking for [std::is_partitioned](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_partitioned)?  Also, `EvenOdd` could have simply used `std::partition`, and then all of the testing would be mostly moot.

Comment: At the link, the answer to your question is right there in the example code where the even numbers are partitioned from the odd numbers, and then tested using `std::is_partitioned`.

Answer (score 0):

IMO tests don't have to contain any logic (e.g. that would require usage of `std::is_partitioned`) but should rather use `Arrange/Act/Assert` approach where you state your inputs, execute code under test and compare output with the expected output that can be hardcoded.

Using functions to generate expectations (rather than hardcoded values) can be dangerous because if you end up using the same algorithm inside you function and to generate the expected output, then if the underlying algorithm doesn't work properly, both your expected and actual output will be incorrect (but the same, so the test would pass!). That rather won't happen when using `std` algos, but it might be tempting to generate the expected output with the same algorithm that is under test - which would be mistake.